# Youtrack and RestSharp Permissions issue

Tags: restsharp, youtrack

I'm trying to create a youtrack client using RestSharp. I can log in, but when I try to get a project, I receive the following response:

{"value":"You do not have permissions to read project. You are logged in as ****"}

However, when I log into YouTrack on my browser, I can access the project and make changes, etc. Attached is my code (I am using RestSharp):

```
var client = new RestClient(Site);

var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("rest/user/login?login={0}&password={1}", Username, Password), Method.POST);

//reuse the client
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;

//returns <login>ok</login> - so it's logging in
Console.WriteLine("LOGIN \n" + content);

String projectId = "PW";
request = new RestRequest(String.Format("rest/admin/project/projectId={0}", projectId), Method.GET);
response = client.Execute(request);
content = response.Content;

Console.WriteLine("Get Project: \n\n" + content);
```

Is there something in the code I'm missing? Or is this a YouTrack setup issue that I need to take up with my administrator?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

I do not have permissions for the /rest/admin resources, but I do have them for /rest/issue. These permissions can be set by the system administrator, if they check the "Groups" in their dashboard.